# What is a digit?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, modern-life, mathematics, numbers

Is there a good Latin word for a digit or figure?
I might want to say that the sum of the digits of 43 is 7 or that an actor was paid a six-figure salary for a movie.
It occurred to me that I don't know any suitable word for this in Latin.
(In Finnish the corresponding word would be "numero", whereas a number would be "luku".)

The Arabic numbers were introduced to Latin too late for there to be much hope to have a suitable word in classical Latin.
The concept of a digit is less meaningfull for numbers like LXXVII (that would be a disappointing six-figure salary!), but perhaps there might be a word for a single symbol in a number.
I pose no era restrictions; I would like to have a word for modern uses like my examples above.

The obvious suspect [*digitus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DD%3Aentry+group%3D34%3Aentry%3Ddigitus1) seems to be inappropriate, at least in classical Latin.
This word might require other words to disambiguate from fingers and toes.

Comment: Just unsourced opinion:1) I think there's no special word for $f(43)=7$ before the X cent.: the positional system (and no. 0) become [known in Europe by that time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals#Adoption_in_Europe) 2) You could add the IV in XL with the III, but I don't think it is intuitive. 3) Some Mediterranean numerical systems used letters w/values as well, and there are examples of numerology (adding the letters in a name to form a number, etc. e.g. Sixtus=i+x+v=16) 4) I think _littera_ could be understandable even if not optimal, as in _summa literarum (nominis/numeris)_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you say, the concept of digits is only meaningful if you are using Indian/Arabic numbers. These became known in Latin Europe by the 12th century, and with them the use of “digitus” for the numbers from 0 to 9. This usage is not classical, but it is of respectable antiquity.